# Combine Adjacent Row Cells Depending on their Left Column Cell

Tags: excel, parsing, concatenation, spreadsheet, vba

I'd like to combine cells in the right column into one cell according to the adjacent cell on the left. I tried Merging but I could only get so far. And after searching online I couldn't find anything that can parse each row and combine for the length of the left cell's span. I know it's a CONCATENATE function, but how would I get it to parse the whole spreadsheet?

[image: Adjacent Cells]

This is an example of the results I would want for the above:

[image]

Comment: What is the maximum amount of merging on the first column? Is it always one or two rows? Or could it be three or even more?

Comment: It's varies. The max one I have is 20 rows with the same left column cell, the least is no duplicates.

Comment: Ok. I made a version that accounts for 2 combinations, but I think if you want to go more than that, VBA would make it easier. So it won't necessarily be all in formulas.

Comment: That's fine. I'm comfortable with using VBA, I'm just not familiar enough to create something off the bat. However, a lot of the rows are 2 combinations, so if I could use that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be too complicated - in which case I would go back to the drawing board and do a full VBA version, but initially I was looking for a challenge to construct a solution only using formulas. Unfortunately, there appears to be no standard formula-based approach to concatenate a variable number of cells.

So, to accomplish this, I added one function:

```
Function CombineRange(ByRef rng As Range, ByVal delim As String)
    Dim arr
    Dim i As Long

    arr = rng.Value

    CombineRange = ""
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        If i > 1 Then
            CombineRange = CombineRange & delim
        End If

        CombineRange = CombineRange & arr(i, 1)
    Next i

End Function
```

Assumptions:

- your data is in a sheet called "YourData"
- Your merged data is column A
- Your "single row" data is column B
- Row 1 is some kind of header row.

[image: your data]

Next, set up four columns on a new sheet (I call it "Collapsed")

A - Start Row = (first row) whatever row your data starts on (2, in our case)

A - Start Row = (all others) `A2+B2`

B - Offset = `{IFERROR(MATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(A2+1,1,,,"YourData")&":A200")),0),0)}`

**Note this is an array function, so you need to do shift+Enter when entering it**

C - Level1 = `=INDEX(YourData!A:A,A2)`

D - Combined Level 2 = `=IF(B2<=1, INDIRECT(ADDRESS(A2,2,,,"YourData")), CombineRange(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(A2,2,,,"YourData")&":"&ADDRESS(A2+B2-1,2)),"; "))`

[image]

Comment: Is there a formula to detect the start row or should I manually enter these?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the first part A Start Rows?

Comment: For the first row, it's just the number 2 (this the row your data starts on).

For other rows, use the formula for column A above.

Comment: D2+E2 gives me 0, how does that calculate the starting row in my original sheet? I understand what it's supposed to do but this isn't giving me my starting rows so my offsets are going to be off

Comment: My mistake - should be A2+B2. I moved the columns over at one point, I am editing the answer now.

Comment: Thank you, I figured but I just wasn't sure. Works, thanks!